# Table grouped hourly and average of value

Tags: java, postgresql

I have this table containing id, date, value, how do I get the hourly average in postgresql?

```
id     date                     value
3470,  2018-11-15 08:10:00+02,  25,101610.0234375
3467,  2018-11-15 07:53:00+02,  33,101398.984375
3468,  2018-11-15 07:54:00+02,  25,101599.765625
3549,  2018-12-28 18:20:00+02,  29.21
3550,  2018-12-28 18:24:00+02,  29.21
3551,  2018-12-28 18:27:00+02,  42.21
3552,  2019-01-07 09:42:00+02,
3553,  2019-01-07 09:50:00+02,  15.140000343323
3554,  2019-01-07 09:52:00+02,  -1.3799999952316
3555,  2019-01-07 10:03:00+02,  14.949999809265
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you could truncate your date to the last hour (e.g. via `date_trunc('minute', date)`) and group on that.

Comment: Record 3552 is missing a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date_trunc('hour', date)` does the job:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7886e9147ba2de3e6706c8f193ec1f92)

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('hour', mydate),
    avg(value)
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY 1
```

If you want to preserve the time zones you need them to be explicitly recognized (date_trunc()) eliminates them:

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('hour', mydate at time zone '0') at time zone '+2',
    avg(value)
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: This won't do the job if the OP expects every hour on each date to be present, even if no data appears for that hour.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do not believe this what the TO expects. Because the date range is too huge for that. Many empty records would be created in that case.

Comment: Yes guys, it solved my problem, I removed the id before the date_trunc in SELECT so it could generate new id's, that was the issue I had problems with :)
Thank you very much.